# Add ' to particular place in String in Java

Tags: java

I have string like following.

```
"pqrs, ABC Inv, ABC Inv; Inc. (us), AAC Inv pqr, abcd"
```

I want to add ' before and after the string which have ; separated by ,. Means, I want ' before and after this string in above example **ABC Inv; Inc. (us)**.
And also wants to remove **;** from that string.

So, my final result would be.

```
"pqrs, ABC Inv, 'ABC Inv Inc. (us)', AAC Inv pqr, abcd"
```

I tried following:

```
public static void main(String []args){
     String s = "pqrs, ABC Inv, ABC Inv; Inc. (us), AAC Inv pqr, abcd";
     
     String[] split = s.split(";");
     String firstStr = split[0];
     String secondStr = split[1];

    int index = firstStr.lastIndexOf(',');
    int index1 = secondStr.indexOf(',');

    
    String newstr =  s.substring(0, index+1) + "'" + s.substring(index+1, index+index1+1) + "'" + s.substring(index+index1+1) ;
    System.out.println(newstr.replaceAll(";", ""));

 }
```

But, not working properly. It give me result like:

```
pqrs, ABC Inv,' ABC Inv 'Inc. (us), AAC Inv pqr, abcd
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You didn't take into account the part of `firstStr` *after* the last comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list is comma separated, with `", "` as a separator so:

- split on `", "`
- for each token:

  - if it has a `";"`, add the two `'` and replace the `";"` by an empty char
  - otherwise leave it alone
- then re-join them using `", "` as a separator

ie, assuming your original String is called `yourString`

```
String result = Arrays.stream(yourString.split(", "))
        .map(s -> s.contains(";")
                ? "'%s'".formatted(s).replace(";", "")
                : s
        )
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
```

Comment: This is not working in following conditions. `"('ABC Inv,ABC Inv; Inc. (us)')"`  or only value like: `"('ABC Inv; Inc. (us)')"`

Comment: There are no parenthesis in your original question, so that is a different problem. My solution only works for the format presented in the original question ie `"token, token, token, token, ..."` where `token` can contain a `;`

Answer (score 1):

Something closer to your original:

```
String newstr =  firstStr.substring(0, index+2) + "'" + firstStr.substring(index+2) + secondStr.substring(0, index1) + "'" + secondStr.substring(index1) ;
System.out.println(newstr);
```

Even closer:

```
String newstr =  s.substring(0, index+1) + "'" + s.substring(index+1, firstStr.length()+index1+1) + "'" + s.substring(firstStr.length()+index1+1) ;
```